# Display keyboard without animation

Tags: iphone, keyboard

Looked into`UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey` but I just can't find anywhere how to set it to a custom value.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

`UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey` is a const string identifier for the dictionary key that holds the animation duration, so there is no way to change it easily.

One way to make the keyboard appear without animation is to observe the keyboard notifications and disable animation when it's about to appear and then reenable them. This, of course, disables any other animation as well.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                         selector:@selector(willShowKeyboard:) 
                                             name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification 
                                           object:nil];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                         selector:@selector(didShowKeyboard:) 
                                             name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification 
                                           object:nil];

- (void)willShowKeyboard:(NSNotification *)notification {
    [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO];
}

- (void)didShowKeyboard:(NSNotification *)notification {
    [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:YES];
}
```

and then then the same for `UIKeyboardWillHideNotification/UIKeyboardDidHideNotification` notifications.

Answer (score 10):

Try

```c
[UIView performWithoutAnimation:^{
    [textField becomeFirstResponder];
}];
```

Answer (score 9):

### iOS8-compatible:

Add the appropriate delegate method:

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO];
}
```

or

```
- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView {
    [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO];
}
```

Add the keyboard notification:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(didShowKeyboard:) name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];
```

And method:

```
- (void)didShowKeyboard:(NSNotification *)notification {
    [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 8):

I've found the best solution is using `UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(_ enabled: Bool)`.

**Swift 3**

```
UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)
textField.becomeFirstResponder()
// or textField.resignFirstResponder() if you want to dismiss the keyboard
UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true)
```

Answer (score 4):

The answer of @Vadoff works perfect. Here for **Swift 3:**

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //...

        // Add observer to notificationCenter so that the method didShowKeyboard(_:) is called when the keyboard did show.
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(type(of: self).didShowKeyboard(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardDidShow, object: nil)

        // Make textField the first responder.
        textField.becomeFirstResponder() // <- Change textField to the name of your textField.
    }

    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        // Disable animations.
        UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)
    }
    func didShowKeyboard(_ notification: Notification) {
        // Enable animations.
        UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true)
    }
```

Comment: You will also need to add the begin editing being target:  `textField..addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidBeginEditing(_:)), for: .editingDidBegin)`

Answer (score -1):

I had to disable Animations in `textViewShouldBeginEditing`, `textFieldDidBeginEditing` did not work for me (iOS 8)

Comment: Providing a code sample would make this a much better answer (note from the review queue). This would be a good answer with code or it could just be a comment/edit on the accepted answer

Answer (score -8):

It is pretty simple guys. Do not use UIView:SetAnimationEnabled as that will be potentially troublesome. This is how i remove animation when keyboard show.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [txtFirstName becomeFirstResponder];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    [txtFirstName resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: The question was to display the keyboard without an animation, not just to display the keyboard.

Comment: This has nothing to do with keyboards animation.