# Show UIKeyboard without animation

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikeyboard

In objective-c when you set `becomeFirstResponder` on `UITextField` the keyboard comes sliding up from the bottom.

Is there any way to disable this animation?

Comment: why do you want to disable the animation? It's normal iphone behavior.,,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

do this it in between animation process, like this

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.0];
    [UIView setAnimationDelay:0.0];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear];

    [textField becomeFirstResponder];

    [UIView commitAnimations];
```

if above not works for any reason then you can use notifications

[see this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1851566/display-keyboard-without-animation)

Comment: The whole second half of your answer is a copy of the answer from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1851566/display-keyboard-without-animation. Please do not steal other people's answers.

Comment: does not work on iOS 7

Comment: works for me in iOS 8.1.3! thank you!

Comment: This works even for iOS 10! Thank you from 2017, man)