# I want my controls to stay put when keyboard is presented

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

It seems like there should be a simple answer to this, but my searching doesn't turn up an answer.

I have a few controls in a UIViewController that resides in a Container View within another UIViewController. When a user taps one of the UITextFields, all the controls in the container view controller move up to accomodate the keyboard being present. I DO NOT WANT THIS ACTION. I simply want them to stay put. I've tried a lot of the obvious solutions, but none are satisfactory.

I have tried some solutions to counteract this behavior, including catching the Notifications for keyboard events and trying to counteract the animations. I do not want a quirky anti-animation. I simply want the controls to stay put when the keyboard is dispatched.

It seems like nowadays (with iOS 6.1) there should be a way to do this just with IB, but I do not see one.

Edit: For example [this post:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1851566/display-keyboard-without-animation) disables the animations, but the controls are still relocated. I do not want them to move at all. Moving them back to their original location is not ideal, rather disable them from moving at all.

It seems like back in iOS 4 or so, you had to move the keyboard yourself, manually. Now it's done automatically, but not always desired. I just want to disable it.

Comment: What are the types of the two view controllers?  Which ones are custom to your app and which are standard iOS types?  What are the superclasses of the ones that are custom to your app?

Comment: I am only inheriting from UIViewController for both the parent and the container view controllers. Very basic, nothing special.

Comment: If I move the controls (UITextField, UIButton) from the child/container UIViewController to the main view controller, they don't relocate when the keyboard is presented. Only when then live in a popup or container view do they do this.