# Which is the better way to communicate between two views?

Tags: ios, design-patterns

One of our our project requires a simple custom keyboard control that will be reused throughout the project's many views and possibly future projects as well.

A question was posed:

**If we know that the keyboard control's sole purpose is to provide the user a way to input data to modify a single UITextField or UILabel is it:**

a) better to pass a reference to that UITextField to the CustomKeyboardView and let that view handle the modification of the textfield's text inside of it's class or:

b) write a delegate for returning the values from the CustomKeyboardView and make the parent viewController handle receiving callbacks from the keyboard and setting the correct value of the UITextField or:

c) do it using some other pattern?

It is worth noting that the code for writing text to the textfield is a bit more involved than simply passing raw characters, it compares the value that is already in the textfield and passes the character according to that state.

Comment: Do you not simply want to make it so that you assign your custom keyboard as the inputView for the UITextField. I would create a subclass of UITextField which wires your reusable keyboard as the inputView. Then in storyboard or in code you just create your text field to be an instance of the subclass.

Comment: @RoryMcKinnel We may need to use the control to modify UILabels and UIButtons as well. Option a) enables us to pass a reference to the control that we want to modify using the keyboard and if it's a control that allows us to set it's text - we set it's text. If it doesn't allow for text changing - we raise an exception.

Comment: I can imagine a scenario where a UIButton is a must but cannot think of any case where a UITextField (with user interction disabled, no border and clear background color) cannot replace a UILabel.. do not use labels..instead use text fields .. and you can use custom view as keyboard for those..

Comment: @SwapnilLuktuke Agreed, UILabel can be replaced with UITextField. What about UIButton then, that does not specify an inputView I take it? Also another question, can you use inputView without the animation that puts the control at the bottom of the screen? Can that control already be a part of the view that the UITextField also belongs to?

Comment: @Jakub. For a UILabel, you would be better to swap it with a UITextField while editing then replace it with a UILabel when done, or just use UITextField altogether. For a UIButton, I am not sure I fully understand the use case unless it is to implement some sort of selector button. Here I would be inclined to again use a UITextField with the same frame as the UIButton so you can simply ask it to becomeFirstResponder to edit the label. As noted before, you then just ask developers to use the updated UIButton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have two views that will be intimately related, what you want is a controller to live between them. That is likely going to be a `UIViewController` that owns the keyboard, and that you hand a `UITextField` or `UILabel` when you create it.

Your "main" view controller can then create this custom one as a child, much as you'd might do with a `UIPopoverController` or `UIAlertController`.

This pattern makes the whole bundle very reusable, without injecting controller logic into the view.

Comment: Option a) was motivated by an issue with code bloat that usually happens in viewControllers. By placing the logic inside the custom control and bypassing the viewController no additional code would have to be written inside the VC. It does make sense though that the viewController (considering it's name) should live between and manage the communication between it's child views. Should it then be taken as a rule that when two child views want to communicate it's the VC that should handle the communication?

Comment: Yes, that's definitely the rule, but I'd say "*a* VC should handle the communication." You don't have to put all coordinating functions in one giant VC. I'm suggesting a smaller, child VC that just coordinates between the keyboard and the other view. VCs only lead to bloat because people dump unrelated coordinating activity in a single massive controller. The child VC I'm suggesting would be reusable, along with the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Continuing from the comment i made above, the easiest way would be to use textfields with your custom view as the input view.

You can easily replace UILabels with UITextFields.

For UIButtons, overlap button with a UITextField. When the textfield is user interaction disabled, it'll pass on all touches to the button (fulfilling normal button behaviour) and when enabled, will be a normal editable text field allowing you to use the custom view as 'inputView'.

If you have just one or two buttons, you can do the same with each button but if you have many buttons you can make a separate control and reuse it throughout the app.

This allows you to 
1. Use robust, default iOS text field delegate infrastructure 
2. Keep using all textfield goodies like placeholder text and clear button while editing etc. if you wish.

You can [avoid inputView animation easily](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1851566/display-keyboard-without-animation). Without the animation, custom view is as good as being a part of your parent view if you make the text field first responder in view will appear.