# How to remove UIKeyboard animation both in sliding up(showing) and sliding down(hiding)? -IOS9 Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have a view where I need to show the keyboard always, but it's not that easy cos I'm presenting another view modally in said view whenever the alert view shows it dismiss my keyboard.

so my fix is to use fake keyboard as imageview and it has image of keyboard now I can show my keyboard anytime, but I would like to remove the transition of keyboard the showing and hiding over my fake keyboard.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1851566/display-keyboard-without-animation) but it's not working on ios9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me if my keyboard is presented:

```
private func presentAlert(alertController: UIAlertController) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        guard let topViewController = UIApplication.sharedApplication().windows.last!.rootViewController else {
            return
        }
        topViewController.presentViewController(alertController, animated:true,
            completion:nil)
    })
}

private func createAlert(title: String, message: String) -> UIAlertController {
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    let cancelAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Cancel) {
        action -> Void in
        // Do something?
    }
    alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
    return alertController
}
```

Then you can call the alert like so:

```
presentAlert(createAlert("Title", message: "Your message here"))
```

Here's a screenshot of it:

[image]

Comment: awesome! but now I'm confuse why it doesn't work the first time ..Thanks man

Comment: I think it was the lack of the dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue). No problem! Glad it worked for you.

Comment: oh I remember, I'm not actually using alertController I'm using viewController with modified framesize to be look like alert.. In that case it presented the view all right but it hide the keyboard. But if I just use alertController it work just fine. Still need to use viewController though