# How can you show/hide keyboard without animation on swift?

Tags: swift, keyboard

How can you show/hide keyboard without animation on swift?
I've tried UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false) on keyboard will appear but doesn't work.

all the other function on my code works but all I want to do is disable the keyboard animation that curves up

Comment: The keyboard is not yours to command.

Comment: See this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1851566/display-keyboard-without-animation)

Answer (score 1):

Turn off all animations on UIView and then dismiss the keyboard. Turn the animations back on when done.

```
UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)
textField.becomeFirstResponder()
// or textField.resignFirstResponder()
UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true)
```